# change the voice for twilio number incoming call

Tags: twilio

We have a twilio number.
When ever any one call on that twilio number then there is an automated voice of twilio play. Can we customize this to a new message?

Thanks,
Rajendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can customise Twilio calls as much as you want! I recommend you take a look through this [QuickStart for handling incoming phone calls with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml) which should get you up and running.

To quickly describe it though, you have a Twilio number and that number has a Voice Request URL configured in the number's settings. When you make a call to that Twilio number, Twilio makes an HTTP request to the URL. That URL needs to return [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) (a set of instructions to Twilio in XML) which tells Twilio what to do with the call.

If you update the URL to something you control and then return different TwiML, then you can change the message and do a whole lot of other stuff with your Twilio number.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind accepting the answer so that others can see that this helped. Thank you!